# Why does a form not need an 'action' attribute? UserCreationForm

Tags: python, html, django

I create a form using django auth forms UserCreationForm and it works without 'action' inside . Why it works?

views.py

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('contacts:index')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

sgnup.html

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because by default your browser will post the form to the current URL. So if your get view and post view share the same URL, it just works.

And that's obviously the case here, since you use the same view for POST and GET.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. Will it work on old browsers?(like IE5-8). Or in practice better to clearly define 'action'?

Comment: wow, that old... :-) To be sure, add the action, it won't hurt. in HTML4, the `action` attribute is mandatory and should be a valid URI, otherwise behaviour is officially undefined. I think an empty string as action has fallen back to the current URL in most browsers for a long time, but I wouldn't place my bets on IE5-8 doing that.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @dirkgroten, in HTML5 it is not mandatory to specify form action, in such cases like yours,  with no action specified-The form is posted to current URL.